# Docker-compose cannot find Flask configuration file

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I followed [this blog post from Pycharm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/) and tried to dockerize my Flask app. My app runs correctly on local venv. But when I use `docker-compose up` in the terminal. I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/CarrotApp/project/instance/flask.cfg'

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD3Mk.png)

I copied the docker related files from the blog post, only made minimal changes:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.6

EXPOSE 5000

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD python run.py
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

My app structrue:

> - project
>
>   - /app (created by Dockerfile)
>   - /instance
>
>     - `flask.cfg`
>   - /venv
>   - `__init__.py`
> - `run.py`
> - requirements.txt
> - `Dockerfile` and `yml` files

`run.py`:

```
from project import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Flask configuration in my `__init__.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True,
            instance_path='/CarrotApp/project/instance')
app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')
```

I had to use absolute path for the instance because Flask only allows such.

I am new to Docker and have no idea where went wrong.

Edit: Changed the yml file according to answer of @andre_vieira . Added screenshot of the complete error message

Comment: Have you already done `docker-compose up --build`?

Comment: Oh I think I did but overlooked the error: `ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile` . But my Dockerfile is right there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying theat you docker file are in the app folder with this line:

```
build: ./app
```

So change it to:

```
build: .
```

This will elimininate the:

```
Cannot locate specified Dockerfile
```

EDIT: about the config file not found.

I cannot understant what are you trying, because, with this line:

```
COPY . /app
```

You are copying all the files to your app folder. So inside the container the paths are like:

```
app/project/app/ 
app/project/instance
app/run
app/Dockerfile and yml files (any you don't need, and you don't want this files inside the container.
```

Is this what you are trying?

Try to 'ssh' to inside the container and check if files exists and to see if the paths are like you want.

Because you say that you app and config file are in the 
/CarrotApp folder. But you never create this folder. So try to change the init to:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True,
            instance_path='/app/project/instance')
app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')
```

EDIT2:

To just pass the files you need, copy only that files:

```
COPY project /app
COPY run.py /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
```

Or just put all this files inside a folder named 'src' or anything else, and copy only that folder:

```
COPY src /app
```

So your structure will be like:

```
 yourproject/
    src/
       project
           /app (created by Dockerfile)
           /instance
               flask.cfg
           /venv
           __init__.py
       run.py
       requirements.txt
    Dockerfile and yml files
```

Comment: Thank you, now the image is successfully built, but I still get the same `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: instance_path='/app/project/instance' worked, thank you! Guess I just need to have a different Flask config for my local venv. I have a follow-up question: what is a better practice for creating/organizing the image path?  I did `COPY . /app' just following the blog post.

Comment: I edited my answer again to match your question. Please take a look